# Why is this pointer needed when calling std::call_once()?

Tags: c++, multithreading, pointers, c++11, this-pointer

In book "C++ Concurrency in Action" §3.3.1, when introducing thread-safe lazy initialization of a class member using `std::call_once()`, it gives the following example:

```
#include <mutex>

struct connection_info
{};

struct data_packet
{};

struct connection_handle
{
    void send_data(data_packet const&)
    {}
    data_packet receive_data()
    {
        return data_packet();
    }
};

struct remote_connection_manager
{
    connection_handle open(connection_info const&)
    {
        return connection_handle();
    }
} connection_manager;


class X
{
private:
    connection_info connection_details;
    connection_handle connection;
    std::once_flag connection_init_flag;

    void open_connection()
    {
        connection=connection_manager.open(connection_details);
    }
public:
    X(connection_info const& connection_details_):
        connection_details(connection_details_)
    {}
    void send_data(data_packet const& data)
    {
        std::call_once(connection_init_flag,&X::open_connection,this);
        connection.send_data(data);
    }
    data_packet receive_data()
    {
        std::call_once(connection_init_flag,&X::open_connection,this);
        return connection.receive_data();
    }
};

int main()
{}
```

From [its doc](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/call_once), the third parameter is the parameter passing to the function `X::open_connection()`. Why is `this` pointer needed here when calling `std::call_once()` given that `X::open_connection()` has no input parameter?

```
std::call_once(connection_init_flag,&X::open_connection,this);
```

P.S.: Removing `this` pointer will cause C2064 error:

> `error C2064: term does not evaluate to a function taking 0 arguments`

---

**Updated:** This issue is further addressed clearly in §4.2.1 of book "C++ Concurrency in Action" when introducing similar functions i.e. `std::async`:

> **If the first argument (should be the second one for `std::call_once`) is a pointer to a member function, the second argument (should be the third one for `std::call_once`) provides the object on which to  apply  the  member  function  (either  directly,  or  via  a  pointer,  or  wrapped  in `std::ref`),  and  the  remaining  arguments  are  passed  as  arguments  to  the  member function.** Otherwise, the second (should be the third one for `std::call_once`) and subsequent arguments are passed as arguments to  the  function  or  callable  object  specified  as  the  first  argument.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

> Why is this pointer needed when calling std::call_once()?

Because `open_connection` is a non-static data member. It has to be called on something, and that something is the same instance, pointed at by `this` (technically, non-static member functions have an implicit first parameter for `this`.)

It could have been invoked with a different instance, although that wouldn't make sense in this case:

```
X x;
std::call_once(connection_init_flag, &X::open_connection, &x);
```

Comment: So it's equivalent to call `this->open_connection()`, right?

Comment: @herohuyongtao It will result in `this->open_connection()` being called once.

Comment: Shouldn't the third parameter be the input parameter for the function indicated by the second parameter of `call_once()`, like examples from [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/call_once)?

Comment: @herohuyongtao Yes and no. The examples have non-member functions. Member functions have an implicit first parameter for `this`. That is how the object's state can be made accessible in them. But `call_once` (and `std::thread`, `std::bind` and others) are not member functions, so they need this first parameter to be passed explicitly. That is the only way they can bind a member function to an instance.

Comment: Clear now. Thanks for your detailed explanation.

Answer (score 8):

juanchopanza is correct, I would like to add that what you are actually doing might have be clearer if you replace the arguments or your code snippet by an strictly equivalent lambda:

```
std::call_once(connection_init_flag, [&]{ open_connection(); } );
// or 
std::call_once(connection_init_flag, [this]{ open_connection(); } );
```

Which is also exactly equivalent to:

```
std::call_once(connection_init_flag, [this]{ this->open_connection(); } );
```